# How to get/set current page URL (which works across space-time-browsers-versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get/set URL of the current page upon certain event.

It seems there are more than one approach for doing it as mentioned in questions/answers below.

Using Jquery

```
Get URL - $(location).attr('href');
Set URL - $(location).attr('href',url);
```

Using JavaScript

```
Get URL - myVar = window.location.href;
Set URL - window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Which approach works across space-time-browsers-versions?

[Get current URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery?rq=1)

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1)

Comment: To change the URL without redirecting the page use [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState), which [works on all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_history_replacestate).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I don't see any need to use jQuery for this. The following will work perfectly fine in all browsers:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Or even more simply:

```
location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @meub . this will also do :

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

To behave as clicking a link you need to use simple javascript . You don't need jQuery for doing that.
You can use the following:

```
Get URL - myVar = window.location.href;
SET URL - window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: window.location.replace as as good as redirect I guess. I mean it is not like clicking on a link, but like being redirected.