# Requests.py Redirect URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When you go to the site, https://www.jimmyjazz.com/search?keywords=11468285, you are redirected to https://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-solar-hu-nmd/BB9528.

I would like to use requests to enter that search link, then return the url that it is redirected to.

Here is my code to do that:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sitename = "https://www.jimmyjazz.com/search?keywords=11468285"
response = requests.get(sitename, allow_redirects=True)
print(response.url)
```

But it still returns the original url:

```
PS C:\Users\jokzc\Desktop\python\learning requests> py test2.py
https://www.jimmyjazz.com/search?keywords=11468285
```

How would I append my code to make fix that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually send a `302` redirect code back. I did the same HTTP GET call in postman, and it appears that it returns a `200` OK response:

[image]

Same goes for chrome dev tools, looking at the network traffic:
[image]

I think that somewhere in their JavaScript code [they are setting the location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396501/how-to-get-set-current-page-url-which-works-across-space-time-browsers-versions) to be a new url. I didn't go through the whole JS stack trace to prove it, but that is my best guess.